# Can you "unroll" an animation in Powerpoint to slides?

Tags: powerpoint

I am currently preparing a "final report" document in Powerpoint that requires me not to include animations. However, the various source documents to be combined include animations.

I am searching for a way to automatically generate a slide for each animation step. Basically the same functionality as exporting the slides to PDF with animation steps, with the difference that the animation steps remain powerpoint slides.

Is there a way to achieve this automatically, or do I have to duplicate the slides and prepare the animation steps myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [PPspliT](http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/%7Erimondin/downloads.php)  add-in for MS Office by a man named Massimo Rimondini. It does exactly what you want. I checked in Office 2013 and it works fine.

---

### Bonus:

In case that plugin fails to remove all the animations and convert into separate slides (which is very unlikely), you can disable any remaining animations for slide show, or remove them altogether using a macro.

#### Disabling animations:

You can turn off the animations by going to "Setup Slide Show" and under "Show Options" tick the "Show without animation" option and click OK. Now run the show and it will display without the animations.

#### Removing animations altogether:

If you really want to delete all the animations in a single sweep then you will need to run this macro.

```
Sub StripAllBuilds()
    Dim I As Integer: Dim J As Integer
    Dim oActivePres As Object
    Set oActivePres = ActivePresentation
    With oActivePres
        For I = 1 To .Slides.Count
            If Val(Application.Version) < 10 Then
                ' Older versions of PowerPoint 97/2000
                ' In each slide set the animation property
                ' of the Shape object to FALSE
                For J = 1 To .Slides(I).Shapes.Count
                    .Slides(I).Shapes(J).AnimationSettings.Animate = msoFalse
                Next J
            Else
              ' New versions support the Timeline object
                For J = .Slides(I).TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1
                    .Slides(I).TimeLine.MainSequence(J).Delete
                Next J
            End If
        Next I
    End With
    Set oActivePres = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, are there any restrictions for Office on OSX? I get a "Compile error in hidden module: PPspliT" there when I use the source package. Is this fixable or do I need to do this in Windows?

Comment: I haven't got an OS X to test. Could you install the program on OS X? As it is an `.exe` file, it should not naturally install on Mac. There is `wine` for running windows application in linux, but I don't the equivalent for OS X. If you can get one, I suggest you use a PC, i.e. a Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it working under Windows. You can also download the source code of the add-in for direct import in Office, but there seems to be some "compile problem" in Office itself. Mac Office seems to be quite different for add-ins, I will try to debug this myself later.